# CSS/JQuery: how to create submenu for table row that stays visible mousing from row onto menu?

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table, hover

I'm a CSS/JQuery rookie, but have built several things with the basics. Just need some general direction.

I have an HTML table (I'm forced to use a table w/ tabular data in this situation) and need to, on hover of a row: 1) draw a line around the row to highlight it, and 2) hook a little dropdown menu to the bottom of the cell that I'm hovering.

My question is: if the menu gets triggered on hover of the row, but you mouse down over the menu, how do you keep the row highlighted and the menu active until you mouse off the menu? I assume the row highlighting and menu itself would disappear when mousing off the row.

For the life of me, I can't find an example of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the `tr`'s `mouseenter` event, assign the row a class of "highlighted" and display your menu.

On the menu's `mouseleave` event hide the menu and remove the "highlighted" class from any row which has it.

Something like :

```
var $myMenu = $('#myMenu');

$('tr').mouseenter(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass('highlighted');
    $myMenu.appendTo($this).slideDown();
});

$myMenu.mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).slideUp();
    $('tr.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
});
```

Comment: OK, I feel silly. I was thinking only in terms of using JQuery's hover to show/hide, which would tie both actions to the same target. I think I get it now. Thanks.

Comment: Don't feel silly, even the most veteran devs forget the most obvious stuff sometimes, way more obvious than this even :)

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, you may want to look at the hoverIntent plugin.  This is a great plugin that works to determine user intent on hover rather than just throwing an immediate action based off of the hover event. It actually has built in functionality for your issue as well. http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Comment: To clarify Vernon's suggestion, Hover intent is for the purpose of delaying a hover event so menus aren't opening and closing all over the place while the user moves his/her cursor around the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try a simple drop down like [this one](http://kimgeekery.blogspot.com/2011/09/jquery-jerky-movements.html) but from a cell.
For the highlights assign a border of the same colour of the cell, then on hover change the border colour.